# Trazer multiplos dados do Django rest filtrado

Tags: axios, django-rest-framework, vuetify, django-filter, vue.js

Bom dia, Como faço para trazer multiplos dados do django rest, por exemplo :

[image: Primeiro resultado]

em vez de aparecer os id dos alunos eu quero trazer os nomes... não sei se é possivel mas espero que seja... estou usando o nuxt.js com vuetify.js, Django rest framework e django filter

```html
<!-- frontend/pages/Index.vue -->
<template>
  <v-card class="mx-auto">
    <v-card-title>{{ evento.descricao }}</v-card-title>

    <v-card-text>
      <h3>Projeto : {{ projeto.descricao }}</h3>
      <div v-for="pp in participanteProjeto" :key="pp.id">
          <h3>Alunos : {{ pp.participante }}</h3>
      </div>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  head() {
    return {
      title: "View Alunos"
    };
  },
  async asyncData({ $axios, params }) {
    try {
      let evento = await $axios.$get(`/eventos/${params.id}`);

      let projeto = await $axios.$get(`/projetos/${evento.projeto}`);

      let participanteProjeto = await $axios.$get(`/participantes-projetos/?evento=${params.id}`);

      //let participantes = await $axios.$get(`/participantes/?grupo=${participanteProjeto.participante}`);

      return { evento, projeto, participanteProjeto };
    } catch (e) {
      return { evento: [], projeto: [], participanteProjeto: [] };
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      evento: {
        descricao: "",
        projeto: ""
      },
      projeto: {
        id: "",
        descricao: ""
      },
      participanteProjeto: {
        id: "",
        participante: ""
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

```py
# api/cadastros/views.py
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import ProjetoSerializer
from .serializers import ParticipanteSerializer
from .serializers import EventoSerializer
from .serializers import ParticipanteProjetoSerializer
from .models import Projeto
from .models import ParticipanteProjeto
from .models import Participante
from .models import Evento
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters


class ProjetoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProjetoSerializer
    queryset = Projeto.objects.all()


class ParticipanteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ParticipanteSerializer
    queryset = Participante.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('id', 'grupo')


class EventoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = EventoSerializer
    queryset = Evento.objects.all()


class ParticipanteProjetoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ParticipanteProjetoSerializer
    queryset = ParticipanteProjeto.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = '__all__'
```

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Projeto(models.Model):

    MATEMATICA = 1
    CIENCIAS = 2

    MATERIA = (
        (MATEMATICA, 'Matemática'),
        (CIENCIAS, 'Ciências')
    )

    QTDMAXMIN = (
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
    (5, '5')
    )

    materia = models.IntegerField(choices=MATERIA)
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    quantidade = models.IntegerField(choices=QTDMAXMIN)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'[{self.get_materia_display()}] - {self.descricao}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Projeto"
        verbose_name_plural = "Projetos"


class Participante(models.Model):

    SEXO = (
        ('F', 'Feminino'),
        ('M', 'Masculino')
    )

    GRUPOS = (
        ('1', 'GRUPO - 1 - CIENCIAS'),
        ('2', 'GRUPO - 2 - CIENCIAS'),
        ('3', 'GRUPO - 3 - CIENCIAS'),
        ('4', 'GRUPO - 4 - CIENCIAS'),
        ('5', 'GRUPO - 1 - MATEMATICA'),
        ('6', 'GRUPO - 2 - MATEMATICA'),
        ('7', 'GRUPO - 3 - MATEMATICA')

    )
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=120)
    sexo = models.CharField(choices=SEXO, max_length=2)
    grupo = models.CharField(choices=GRUPOS, max_length=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Participante"
        verbose_name_plural = "Participantes"


class Evento(models.Model):
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    projeto = models.ForeignKey(
        to='cadastros.Projeto', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.descricao

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Evento"
        verbose_name_plural = "Eventos"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().save(*args, **kwargs)

       projetos = Projeto.objects.filter(pk=self.projeto_id).first()
       quantidade = projetos.quantidade
       for p in range(0, quantidade):
           ParticipanteProjeto.objects.update_or_create(evento=self,ordem=p+1)


class ParticipanteProjeto(models.Model):
    evento = models.ForeignKey(
        to='cadastros.Evento', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
    ordem = models.IntegerField(default=0) 
    participante = models.ForeignKey(
        to='cadastros.Participante', 
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        null=True,
        blank=True
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.pk}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Participante Projeto"
        verbose_name_plural = "Participantes Projetos"
```

```py
# api/cadastros/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Projeto
from .models import Participante
from .models import Evento
from .models import ParticipanteProjeto
# Register your models here.

@admin.register(Projeto)
class ProjetoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('descricao', 'materia')

@admin.register(Participante)
class ParticipanteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'nome')

class ParticipanteProjetoInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ParticipanteProjeto

@admin.register(Evento)
class EventoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('descricao', 'projeto')
    inlines = [
       ParticipanteProjetoInLine
   ]
```

o codigo inteiro esta aqui : [feira-de-ciencias-matematica](https://github.com/FRebeca/feira-ciencias-matematica)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver desse jeito essa minha duvida :

no index.vue :

```html
<template>
  <v-card class="mx-auto">
    <v-card-title>{{ evento.descricao }<v-card-title>

    <v-card-text>
      <h3>Projeto : {{ projeto.descricao }}</h3>
      <div v-for="pp in participantes" :key="pp.id">
        <h3>Alunos : {{ pp.nome }}</h3>
      </div>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  head() {
    return {
      title: "View Alunos"
    };
  },
  async asyncData({ $axios, params }) {
    try {
      let evento = await $axios.$get(`/eventos/${params.id}`);

      let projeto = await $axios.$get(`/projetos/${evento.projeto}`);

      let participanteProjeto = await $axios.$get(
        `/participantes-projetos/?evento=${params.id}`
      );
      let participantes = await $axios.$get(
        `/participantes/?grupo=${params.id}`
      );
      //;

      return { evento, projeto, participanteProjeto, participantes };
    } catch (e) {
      return {
        evento: [],
        projeto: [],
        participanteProjeto: [],
        participantes: []
      };
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      evento: {
        descricao: "",
        projeto: ""
      },
      projeto: {
        id: "",
        descricao: ""
      },
      participanteProjeto: {
        id: "",
        participante: ""
      },
      participantes: []
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

removi o comentario do let participantes e no final da url coloquei `/?grupo=${params.id}` o que significa que eu tive que adicional um novo campo no back então eu fui pro meu models e adicionei a seguinte linha no modelo de participantes :

```py
 grupo = models.CharField(choices=GRUPOS, max_length=2)
```

e adicionei o choices, ja tentei colocar o foreignkey só que ele ficou dependendo de outras coisas então eu desisti dele e adicionei essas linhas

```py
GRUPOS = (
        ('1', 'GRUPO - 1 - CIENCIAS'),
        ('2', 'GRUPO - 2 - CIENCIAS'),
        ('3', 'GRUPO - 3 - CIENCIAS'),
        ('4', 'GRUPO - 4 - CIENCIAS'),
        ('5', 'GRUPO - 1 - MATEMATICA'),
        ('6', 'GRUPO - 2 - MATEMATICA'),
        ('7', 'GRUPO - 3 - MATEMATICA')

    )
```

então comecei a filtrar pelo grupo !

no final de tudo, ficou assim [image: img1]
e adicionei uma validação de nota no front ;) ! ent. foi só issuh, não sei se esta certo mas consegui desse jeito...